# Logging power / battery events

Tags: windows, events, logging, scheduled-tasks

Just bought an APC battery backup and hooked up the USB data cable to my Windows 7 computer.  It automatically installed a driver and now down in the Windows Tray I see a battery with a power plug icon and it shows a charge percentage.  When I unplug the UPS from the wall, the desktop goes to battery mode and the little icon changes ... just like it's a laptop.

What I'd like to do is run a task when this event happens.  Unfortunately, a change in the power status does not log an event in the Event Viewer so that I can attach a task to it.  Obviously something is happening because the icon is changing.  How can I log an event when the power status changes to battery?

Thanks,
AD

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with a script running all the time using WMI notifications.  Below is a script that watches for changes to objects in the Win32_Battery WMI class and reports on the changes made:

```
strComputer = "."

' Connect to WMI
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

'Create the Sink object used for the asynchronous notification.
Set objSink = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink","SINK_")

' Send the query asynchronously.  The SINK_OnObjectReady subroutine will be
' called if any data comes in.
objWMIService.ExecNotificationQueryAsync objSink, "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE " _
    & "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Battery'"

while 1
    Wscript.Sleep(1000)
Wend

Sub SINK_OnCompleted(iHResult, objErrorObject, objAsyncContext)
    WScript.Echo "Asynchronous operation is done."
End Sub

Dim intLastLevel
intLastLevel = 0

Sub SINK_OnObjectReady(objObject, objAsyncContext)
    ' This runs whenever a change is made to the Win32_Battery object for 
    ' your computer's battery.  For more useful properties of this class, 
    ' see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074(v=vs.85).aspx
    Set objEvent=objObject.TargetInstance

    Select Case objEvent.BatteryStatus
        Case 1
            if intLastLevel <> objEvent.EstimatedChargeRemaining Then
                Wscript.Echo "Battery is discharging."
                Wscript.Echo "Battery has", objEvent.EstimatedChargeRemaining + 1, "% left on battery."
                Wscript.Echo "Battery has", objEvent.EstimatedRunTime, " minutes left on battery."
                intLastLevel = objEvent.EstimatedChargeRemaining
            End If
        Case 2
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is connected to AC."
        Case 3
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is fully charged."
        Case 4
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is currently low."
        Case 5
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is currently critically low."
        Case 6
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is currrently charging."
            Wscript.Echo "Battery has", objEvent.BatteryRechargeTime, "minutes until it is fully charged."
        Case 7
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is currrently charging and has high charge."
            Wscript.Echo "Battery has", objEvent.BatteryRechargeTime, "minutes until it is fully charged."
        Case 8
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is currrently charging and has low charge."
            Wscript.Echo "Battery has", objEvent.BatteryRechargeTime, "minutes until it is fully charged."
        Case 9
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is currrently charging and has critically low charge."
            Wscript.Echo "Battery has", objEvent.BatteryRechargeTime, "minutes until it is fully charged."
        Case 10
            Wscript.Echo "Battery doesn't know what's going on."
        Case 11
            Wscript.Echo "Battery is partially charged."
    End Select

End Sub
```

Hope this helps, drop me a line if you have any questions.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to drop you a line.  My question:  What language is this script written in?